# Feature Layer no longer accesible after MakeFeatureLayer_management

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, error-000628

I am creating a new layer out of an old one with `MakeFeatureLayer_management` like this:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("layername", "newlayername", "DEPTH = 1200")
```

This works for the first time but if I want to execute the function on the same layer again (with a new `out_layer` and a different `where clause`) like this:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("layername", "secondlayername", "DEPTH = 1400")
```

I get

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "", line 1, in 
>      File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 5774, in MakeFeatureLayer
>        raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Make Feature Layer). Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter in_features.

Also the auto completion for `in_features` no longer shows the used layer.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the edits to your original question, try something like this:

```
import arcpy

input = "featureclass or shapefile"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input, "newlayer", "query")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(input, "newlayer2", "query")
```

Make the input to the MakeFeatureLayer management tool the dataset rather than a layer created from the dataset.

Comment: I'm sorry I seem to have not phrased my question good enough: I want to create multiple new layers out of the original layer. Each layer will only have one where clause though. The problem is that for the second execution (with a different where clause but the same input layer) the input layer is no longer accesible

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully make this a little clearer

Comment: making the input a featureclass instead of a layer created from the dataset seems to have solved the problem. Thank you!